# npm install stuck followed by "Cannot find module" error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to install Material UI, but when I run the command:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

the installation gets stuck at the end for a minute and I get the following error:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\install.js'
```

I tried various fixes I found on other posts, like deleting node_modules and the package-lock.json file and then running npm install, or running "npm cache clear --force", but nothing worked and I got the same error.

Comment: Hello! Your problem seems to be related to your NPM installation on Windows. Did you check that the installation was done right?

Comment: please share the node and npm versions